Computational complexity of deciding if two elements are in the same cycle of a permutation
Given $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have a bijection $P:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$, i.e. $P$ is a permutation of $2^n$ symbols, $P\in S_{2^n}$. The permutation $P$ can be calculated efficiently, i.e. by a reversible circuit composed by a number of Toffoli gates that is polynomial in $n$.
I focus on the problem of deciding if, given $a,b\in\{0,1\}^n$, they belong to the same cycle of $P$.
More rigorously: given the representation of circuit that calculates $P$ and two elements $a,b\in\{0,1\}^n$, is there an integer $\alpha$ such that $P^{\alpha}(a)=b$?
A brute-force algorithm runs in exponential time and polynomial space in $n$, so the decision problem is trivially in PSPACE, but I do not find reasons to think that it is in NP, not to say in P. Surprisigly, I do not even find anything in literature, maybe I am not looking in the right place.
EDIT: after seeing the first comments, I realized that the difficulty stays in the condition that $P$ is a permutation. I remark again this point.
I would like to know if the problem is in P or not. So I would like to have, either: i) an explicit polynomial time algorithm for solving the problem, or ii) an example of a set of $P$ for which the decision problem is likely not in P, e.g. NP-hard.

This is almost certainly PSPACE-complete. It would trivially be so if we remove the requirement that P is a bijection, and I suspect that can be dodged with a bit of cleverness.

@Geoffrey Irving : is the proof (without bijection condition) available in literature? If not, why do not you sketch it as an answer, highlighting the possible changes for the bijection? Actually, proving that the problem is NP-hard would be enough for me and, maybe, it makes the proof easier.

@DorianoBrogioli Fix a PSPACE machine $M$. Given an input $x$ of length $n$, let $P\colon{0,1}^{n^{O(1)}}\to{0,1}^{n^{O(1)}}$ be a circuit implementing the function that takes a configuration of $M$ as run on an input of length $n$, and computes the next configuration. Let $a$ be the initial configuration corresponding to input $x$, and let $b$ be the accepting configuration (assume there is only one; e.g., let $M$ erase all its tapes before accepting).

This solves the problem for a generic $P$. However, I am still not able to bring it to the case of permutations. The machine should be reversible, but then it would produce a lot of garbage that remains stored somewhere. As you remarked, the machine should erase the tape before accepting, but a reversible machine cannot.

The result by Lange, McKenzie and Tapp, Reversible Space Equals Deterministic Space, should be able to complete the proof.

As noted in the comments, the problem is easily shown PSPACE-complete when $P$ is not required to be a permutation.
I do not immediately see how to prove that for permutations (though it sounds plausible that it is still PSPACE-complete), however let me observe that the problem is at least $\mathbf{\oplus P}$-hard, hence hard for the polynomial hierarchy under randomized reductions. A similar argument shows that it is $\mathbf{Mod}_p\mathbf P$-hard for all primes $p$.
To see this, given a CNF $\phi$ in $n$ variables, let $P\colon\{0,1\}^n\times\{0,1\}\to\{0,1\}^n\times\{0,1\}$ be the permutation defined by
$$P(e,a)=(e',a\oplus\phi(e)),$$
where $e'$ denotes the successor of $e$ in the lexicographic cyclic order on $\{0,1\}^n$. (This should be straightforward to implement with reversible gates; if you need a few ancilla bits, you can take instead $P\colon\{0,1\}^n\times\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}^{n'}\to\{0,1\}^n\times\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}^{n'}$, $P(e,a,x)=(e',a\oplus\phi(e),x)$.) Then there exists $\alpha$ such that $P^\alpha(\vec0,0)=(\vec0,1)$ iff the number of satisfying assignments of $\phi$ is odd.

Curiously, the two elements called $a$ and $b$ in the question do not play any role: once $P$ is given, the difficult part of the problem is to decide if it has a single cycle or two; then, it is easy to say if any couple $a,b$ belong to the same cycle, whatever are $a$ and $b$.

I posted a second question, related to this topic: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/472280/computational-complexity-of-deciding-if-two-elements-are-in-the-same-cycle-of-a

It's pretty much the same question. Just make $\phi$ an input of $P$ rather than an input of a reduction that constructs $P$: $P(\phi,e,a)=(\phi,e',a\oplus\phi(e))$ (and let $P$ act as identity if the input does not have the right syntactic form).
