Computational complexity of deciding if two elements are in the same cycle of a permutation, version 2
This question has relation with this previous one, although the two cases are not likely solved with the same method.
Let us consider a function $P:\{0,1\}^*\to\{0,1\}^*$ that can be calculated in polynomial time in the input. It preserves the length of the string. Restricting it to $\{0,1\}^n$, it is a bijection: $P:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ is a permutation of $2^n$ elements.
Now consider the following decision problem associated to $P$:
Two strings $a,b\in\{0,1\}^*$, with the same length, $|a|=|b|$, are given. Do they belong to the same cycle of $P$? More rigorously: is there an $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $P^m(a)=b$?
Clearly, for some $P$, the problem is in P, e.g. for $P(x)=x$. Is it possible to find a $P$ such that the problem is likely more complex, e.g. NP-complete?
The difference of this question with respect to this previous one is that, there, $P$ was an input of the decision problem, in the form of a representation of a circuit calculating $P$. It was shown that the decision problem is at least $\oplus$P-hard. Moreover, if we do not require $P$ to be a permutation, than the problem is PSPACE-complete. At variance with the present case, these proofs focused on the size of the representation of $P$ rather than on the size of the inputs $a$ and $b$, so they do not apply to this question.

This is essentially the same question. If you get any hardness for the previous question, you get the same hardness for this question, considering the poly-time permutation $P(C,x)=(C,C(x))$ that takes a reversible circuit $C$ and applies it to an input $x$ (acting as identity on inputs that are not of the right syntactic shape, i.e., they are not a pair whose first component is a reversible circuit and the second component a string that can be passed to the circuit).
